# Implementing strnstr

Tags: c, string, strstr

I am trying to implement a strnstr function into C (strstr but it checks the length), for some reason it doesn't work (output is always no):

```
#include <stdio.h>

char *searchingFor = "stackdummy";
char *in = "la da\ndoo a da\nnow here comes the stack\nok there it was.\n";

char *strnstr(char *s1, char *s2, int length) {
    if(s1 == NULL || s2 == NULL) return NULL;
    printf("searching \n\n\"%s\"\n for %.*s\n", s1, length, s2);
    char *ss1 = malloc(strlen(s1) + 1);
    strcpy(ss1, s1);
    char *ss2 = malloc(length + 1);
    strncpy(ss2, s2, length);
    char *result = strstr(ss1, ss2);
    free(ss1);
    free(ss2);
    return result;
}

int main(void) {
    printf("found: %s\n", strnstr(in, searchingFor, 5) ? "yes" : "no");
    printf("found: %s\n", strnstr(in, searchingFor, 5) ? "yes" : "no");
    printf("found: %s\n", strnstr(in, searchingFor, 5) ? "yes" : "no");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `strncpy` does not add a terminating  zero.

Comment: Well, at least it's [in the documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strncpy).

Comment: @MOehm my mistake, really. There's nothing wrong with pointers in a Boolean context. Thanks for the critique, btw :)

Comment: @7heo.tk: Well, I haven't said anything, then.

Comment: 1) After `strncpy(ss2, s2, length);`, add `ss2[length] = '\0';` to insure  `ss2` is terminated.  2) note: returning  pointer to a malloc'd variable.

Comment: An alternative implementation can be found here: [Simple and safe implementation](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/132519/a-simple-and-safe-implementation-for-strnstr-search-for-a-substring-in-the-firs)

Comment: I am and I think others are confused by the question since the function, strnstr is in FreeBSD. It has different semantics than what I assume yours does. But, you may not know about that function or be trying to mimic its behavior. I suspect the comment from chux and others about terminating the string may make your test pass. ... but, it returns a pointer to freed memory. That is asking for a hard crash! If you want to return a boolean indication, then return something like !!result and declare result as bool or int or similar.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The implementation provided by [Chris Dodd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16406/chris-dodd) has the following disadvantages:

1. It defeats the purpose of `strnstr` in that the `while` condition uses the unbounded string function `strchr`
2. It depends on `haystack` being NULL terminated, which is a deviation from the usual implementation of `strnstr`, for example as provided by [GNU-Darwin](http://src.gnu-darwin.org/src/lib/libc/string/strnstr.c.html)
3. The call to `strchr` is an unnecessary function call when `strchar` is not inlined
4. Returns `haystack` instead of `NULL` when `len` is zero, a deviation from the accepted `strstr` semantics
5. Returns an empty string instead of `haystack` when `needle` has length of zero

The following implementation remedies the above problems without becoming as difficult to read as the GNU-Darwin implementation, and is Creative Commons licensed:

```
#include <string.h>

char *strnstr(const char *haystack, const char *needle, size_t len)
{
        int i;
        size_t needle_len;

        if (0 == (needle_len = strnlen(needle, len)))
                return (char *)haystack;

        for (i=0; i<=(int)(len-needle_len); i++)
        {
                if ((haystack[0] == needle[0]) &&
                        (0 == strncmp(haystack, needle, needle_len)))
                        return (char *)haystack;

                haystack++;
        }
        return NULL;
}
```

Comment: This seems broken as it will fail in the OP's code, because it runs off the end of `needle` (which is not null terminated).  Also, `strchr` (or `memchr`) is generally faster than a 1-char-at-a-time for-loop, as it usually works word-at-a-time.

Comment: @ChrisDodd: You are correct regarding `needle`. However the NULL termination is required in all of the common string library (Linux, Mac, FreeBSD) implementations and so my assumption was that the OP really meant `strnstr` when he wrote `strnstr`. Regarding the use of `strchr` instead of a one-at-a-time loop, `strchr` itself is implemented as a one-at-a-time loop, so moving the loop to `strnstr` saves the function call overhead. The `memchr` implementation is even slower than `strchr`, and here you would need to add an additional test for a NULL character before `len` chars.

Comment: This doesn't work if len == strlen(needle) which looks like a pretty common scenario.

Comment: @almosnow Whoops, your right. Off by one error. Try it now. Thanks!

Comment: There's a difference between the real strnstr and this tho, as the real one crashes (segmentation fault) when NULL is given for big and len is greater than the length of needle. In your case the for doesn't execute (cause len_little - len is negative) so the program doesn't reach if((haystack[0]....) to crash since it attempts NULL + 0, so your implementation doesn't crush whereas the real one does.

Might not seem like much, but if you want an implementation that matches strnstr in everything the real one does, then you have to account for crashes as well.

Comment: One more difference between this implementation and BSD one when calling with the following arguments: `strnstr("abcdef", "abc", 2)`. This impl returns ptr to haystack, the BSD impl returns NULL. NULL is correct because we only should use 2-char portion of haystack.

Comment: I'm afraid your implementation is incorrect: `len` is the maximum number of characters from `haystack` to consider, all characters in null terminated `needle` must match a portion of the first `len` characters of `haystack`.

Comment: "Returns haystack instead of NULL when len is zero, a deviation from the accepted strstr semantics". Doesn't this implementation do the same? in "if (0 == (needle_len = strnlen(needle, len))) return (char *)haystack";

Answer (score 3):

How about:

```
char *strnstr(char *haystack, char *needle, size_t len) {
    if (len == 0) return haystack; /* degenerate edge case */
    while (haystack = strchr(haystack, needle[0])) {
        if (!strncmp(haystack, needle, len)) return haystack;
        haystack++; }
    return 0;
}
```

If you want `haystack` to not be null terminated, you'll need two length args:

```
char *memmem(char *haystack, size_t hlen, char *needle, size_t nlen) {
    if (nlen == 0) return haystack; /* degenerate edge case */
    if (hlen < nlen) return 0; /* another degenerate edge case */
    char *hlimit = haystack + hlen - nlen + 1;
    while (haystack = memchr(haystack, needle[0], hlimit-haystack)) {
        if (!memcmp(haystack, needle, nlen)) return haystack;
        haystack++; }
    return 0;
}
```

which is available in GNU libc, though older versions are broken.

Comment: Wow, that's a much cleaner approach than mine.

Comment: Though first line should also check for if(len == 0 || !haystack || !needle) return haystack;

Comment: As written its analogous to strncmp -- `len == 0` is well defined as comparing zero chars, but passing a null pointer is undefined if `len > 0`.

Comment: @ChrisDodd Possibly pointless optimization, but given that you've already identified `haystack[0] == needle[0]`, you could `strncmp(haystack+1, needle+1, len-1)`... I guess the pointer adjustments could potentially outweigh the gain from not re-comparing the first character in some cases...

Comment: This approach is also pathologically slow (quadratic time). If your system has `memmem` (nonstandard but fairly common) I think it could be used to implement "strnstr" efficiently, but doing so is not entirely trivial still.

Comment: Note: This code does not prevent reading `&haystack[len]` and beyond.

Comment: @R: This is O(nm) time, not quadratic, and is slower than optimal only on pathological inputs.  @chux: `len` is the length of `needle` and has no relation to the length of `haystack`.

Comment: FreeBSD's version of `strnstr` treats `len` as length of portion of haystack to scan, not the length of needle. In your code you also treat it this way: `if (len == 0) return haystack;`, `if (nlen == 0) return haystack;` (which contradicts your comment). So results of your implementation differ from FreeBSD ones, e.g. for `std::strnstr("abcdef", "abc", 2)` and `std::strnstr("abcdef", "bcd", 3)`.

Answer (score 0):

The `strnstr` function is not defined in the C Standard, it is available on [BSD](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=strnstr&sektion=3) and some other systems as an extension.

Here is the man page on OS/X:

> **NAME**
>
> `strstr`, `strcasestr`, `strnstr` -- locate a substring in a string
>
> **LIBRARY**
>
> Standard C Library (libc, -lc)
>
> **SYNOPSIS**
>
> ```
>     #include <string.h>
> ```
>
> [...]
>
> ```
>     char *strnstr(const char *haystack, const char *needle, size_t len);
> ```
>
> [...]
>
> **DESCRIPTION**
>
> [...]
>
> The `strnstr()` function locates the first occurrence of the null-terminated string `needle` in the string `haystack`, where not more
> than `len` characters are searched.  Characters that appear after a `'\0'` character are not searched.  Since the `strnstr()` function
> is a FreeBSD specific API, it should only be used when portability is not a concern.
>
> **RETURN VALUES**
>
> If `needle` is an empty string, `haystack` is returned; if `needle` occurs nowhere in `haystack`, `NULL` is returned; otherwise a pointer
> to the first character of the first occurrence of `needle` is returned.
>
> **EXAMPLES**
>
> The following sets the pointer `ptr` to the `"Bar Baz"` portion of `largestring`:
>
> ```
>        const char *largestring = "Foo Bar Baz";
>        const char *smallstring = "Bar";
>        char *ptr;
>
>        ptr = strstr(largestring, smallstring);
> ```
>
> The following sets the pointer `ptr` to `NULL`, because only the first 4 characters of `largestring` are searched:
>
> ```
>        const char *largestring = "Foo Bar Baz";
>        const char *smallstring = "Bar";
>        char *ptr;
>
>        ptr = strnstr(largestring, smallstring, 4);
> ```

This specification is not concise enough, (the [man page](https://www.kernel.org/doc/htmldocs/kernel-api/API-strnstr.html) for the linux kernel version is even more imprecise), yet the example on BSD systems (notably above here) is clear: `len` is the maximum number of bytes to consider in `haystack`, not `needle`, which is just a regular null terminated C string.

Your function does not work for multiple reasons:

- the semantics are incorrect as you consider `length` to limit `s2` instead of `s1`
- in your approach, duplicating `s1` is useless and counter-productive: `result`, if non `NULL`, will point into the allocated copy that is freed before returning from the function, hence accessing the string pointed to by the return value will have undefined behavior.
- `strncpy` does not null terminate the destination array if the source string has at least `length` characters before its own null terminator. You must set `ss2[length] = '\0';` for your approach to work, but again, the real `strnstr()` function operates differently.
- using `malloc()` and `free()` is probably not what you are expected to do, and failing to test for potential allocation failure is a mistake.

Here is a corrected version:

```c
char *strnstr(const char *s1, const char *s2, size_t n) {
    // simplistic algorithm with O(n2) worst case
    size_t i, len;
    char c = *s2;

    if (c == '\0')
        return (char *)s1;

    for (len = strlen(s2); len <= n; n--, s1++) {
        if (*s1 == c) {
            for (i = 1;; i++) {
                if (i == len)
                    return (char *)s1;
                if (s1[i] != s2[i])
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

Comment: I suspect that the OP is not trying to mimic the behavior of the FreeBSD function with the same name. But this thread is so old we'll probably never know.