# String search in packet and printing packet data

Tags: c, string, search, pcap

How can I do a string search in a packet (including headers and payload) in C? I tried using strstr(), but because my dest MAC address begins with a 0x00, the strstr() function seemed to not go any further into the packet. Furthermore, there is likely to be more 0x00 bytes within the packet. Do I need to do a byte-by-byte search, or is there a faster way?

Also, can I print the packet data using `%s`? I tried the following, but there was no output.

```
while ((rc = pcap_next_ex(pcap, &pkthdr, &data)) >= 0)
   printf("%s\n", data);
```

Comment: If a MAC address might start with a 0x00, how do you determine its end?  Fixed length? `rc`?

Comment: I want to search through the entire packet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Printing:

You can not print the packet using printf("%s", data) . This is because printing is terminated when a NULL byte ('\0') is occured, which is very frequent when referring to transmitted data. You could use the following to print %len bytes out of %str while ignoring NULL bytes, but it won't get you any far since most bytes are invisible:

```
// len = pkthdr.len
printf("%.*s", len, str);
```

As for searching, you can use the non-standard function strnstr :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char *strnstr(const char *haystack, const char *needle, size_t len)
{
        int i;
        size_t needle_len;

        /* segfault here if needle is not NULL terminated */
        if (0 == (needle_len = strlen(needle)))
                return (char *)haystack;

        for (i=0; i<=(int)(len-needle_len); i++)
        {
                if ((haystack[0] == needle[0]) &&
                        (0 == strncmp(haystack, needle, needle_len)))
                        return (char *)haystack;

                haystack++;
        }
        return NULL;
}

int main()
{
    char big_str[] = "abc\0cde\0efg\0";

    printf("%s", strnstr(big_str, "efg", 12));

    return 0;
}
```

but read this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/25705264/6814540