# Faster way to find a sub-string given beginning and end positions in another string using C++?

Tags: c++, string

The task is to find a substring (needle) in another string (haystack), given the beginning position  and end position of the "haystack". The the beginning and end positions follow STL convention, i.e. the end position is the position of the character following the interested range.

For example: find "567" with `beg_pos=0` and `end_pos=8` in "0123456789" should return `5`, while find "567" with `beg_pos=0` and `end_pos=4` in "0123456789" should return `-1`.

I could imagine two simple implementations:

- **Method 1**: Use `size_t pos = haystack.find(needle, beg_pos);` to get the substring position, then compare the return value `pos` with `end_pos` if found. In the worst case, the `find` function will go until the end of the string `haystack`, but the search after `end_pos` is unnecessary. The performance might be bad if `haystack` is long.
- **Method 2**: Use `size_t pos = haystack.substr(beg_pos, end_pos-beg_pos).find(needle);` to find the position, then return `pos+beg_pos` if found. This method avoids the problem of unnecessary searching after `end_pos`, but it requires to allocate a new temporary string, which might also have performance issue.

I am wondering if there is a faster way to accomplish the task.

Comment: Do you have access to C++17?

Comment: std::string doesn't offer a way to limit the search range. Use C++17 std::string_view as the haystack, use regex search which accepts a pair of iterators, or implement your own search that accepts a pair of iterators.

Comment: Look for `strnstr`. You could build it yourself, here are some implementations: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23999797/implementing-strnstr

Comment: @NathanOliver Yes. I could use C++17.

Answer (score 1):

In C++17 we have [`std::string_view`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view) which can be constructed with a pointer and and size.  This will allow you to get a read only slice of the string where nothing would be copied.  You can then use [`std::string_view::find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view/find) to find if the sub string exists in that slice.  That would look like

```
std::string haystack = "lots of stuff";
std::string needle = "something";
std::string_view slice(haystack.c_str() + start, end - start); // use end - start to get size of the slice
auto pos = slice.find(needle);
if (pos == std::string::npos)
    return -1;
else
    return pos; // or pos + start if you need the index from the start and not just in the slice.
```

Comment: surely it should be this?
`auto pos_slice = slice.find(needle) ; auto pos = (pos_slice == std::string::npos) ? pos_slice : pos_slice + start;`

Comment: @RichardHodges I'm not exactly sure what the OP needs in the end so I figured If I got the position it is in in the slice they can transform that to what they need.

Answer (score 0):

pre-c++17

Here is a method which I think is optimally quick. It uses `std::search`, which seems to me to be an iterator-based substr.

In this example the position of the needle is returned relative to the start of the haystack, not the substring being searched:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    using namespace std::literals;

    auto my_haystack = "0123456789"s;

    auto needle = "567"s;
    auto find_needle = [&needle](auto first, auto last)
    {
        auto i = std::search(first, last, begin(needle), end(needle));
        if (i == last)
            return std::string::npos;
        else
            return std::string::size_type(std::distance(first, i));
    };

    auto in_substring = [](auto&& str, auto b, auto e, auto&& f) -> std::string::size_type
    {
        using std::begin;
        auto brange = begin(str) + b;
        auto erange = begin(str) + e;
        auto p = f(brange, erange);
        if (p != std::string::npos)
            p += b;
        return p;
    };

    auto pos = in_substring(my_haystack, 0, 4, find_needle);
    std::cout << pos << std::endl;

    pos = in_substring(my_haystack, 0, my_haystack.size(), find_needle);
    std::cout << pos << std::endl;

    pos = in_substring(my_haystack, 1, my_haystack.size(), find_needle);
    std::cout << pos << std::endl;

    pos = in_substring(my_haystack, 1, 4, find_needle);
    std::cout << pos << std::endl;
}
```

example output (64-bit `size_type`):

```
18446744073709551615
5
5
18446744073709551615
```